# Slow getting posts from category

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

My blog has over 700,000 articles
and my category structure as follows:

- -Cats

  - Cat 1 (ID: 3)
  - Cat 2 (ID: 4)
  - Cat 3 (ID: 5) ...
  - Cat 20 (ID: 22)

I took the articles by using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT ID FROM apk_posts INNER JOIN apk_term_relationships ON (apk_posts.ID = apk_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN apk_term_taxonomy ON (apk_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = apk_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE (apk_term_taxonomy.term_id = IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22)
AND apk_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category') ORDER BY apk_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 10;
```

And for that the query is very slow (about **3 seconds**).

How can I speed up the query?

Comment: What I learned few days ago that MySQL `JOIN` is a very heavyweight considering load time. I had a similar situation. I had used `Wordpress Transients API`. It will help to reduce the load time, unless you change your query frequently.

Answer (score 0):

> My blog has over 700,000 articles...

You need to look at your webhost and server. WordPress is perfectly scalable, but you need the hardware to back it up. That's a database intensive query, and you need the MySQL server to handle it.

Run mysqltuner.pl https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl to check your MySQL configurations and adjust cache and memory settings in my.cnf.

Comment: thank songdogtech but it's not faster

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: yes, I have used mysqltuner to adjust parameters to my.cnf
advice when changing parameters in the my.cnf file, I have followed
and as a result only change cache_size and BUFFER_SIZE
I had to adjust and find more speed is due to cache
but if the page does not exist query to cache the faster speed is not